# cypher not returning rows with multiple combined match statement

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I ran two Cypher queries which gives me some result

Cypher 1:

```
neo4j-sh (?)$ MATCH (a: Answer { id: "answerID" })<-[:CHOSE]-(u: User) 
> RETURN count(u);                                                                     
+----------+
| count(u) |
+----------+
| 1        |
+----------+
1 row
19 ms
```

Cypher 2:

```
neo4j-sh (?)$ MATCH (q: Question)-[:ANSWER]->(a: Answer { id: "answerID" })
> RETURN count(q);
+----------+
| count(q) |
+----------+
| 1        |
+----------+
1 row
14 ms
```

But combining these two condition gives me zero results

```
neo4j-sh (?)$ MATCH (q: Question)-[:ANSWER]->(a: Answer { id: "answerID" })<-[:CHOSE]-(u: User)
> RETURN count(u);
+----------+
| count(u) |
+----------+
| 0        |
+----------+
1 row
31 ms
```

Is there anything wrong with this query? Help!

Comment: That's really odd... When I create some sample data and copy/paste your queries into my console I get `1` for all of them.  What version of Neo4j are you using?

Comment: It's neo4j-enterprise-2.1.6. Yeah its looks odd, I could not figure what's wrong

Comment: peculiar - what about if you combine them this way `MATCH (q: Question)-[:ANSWER]->(a: Answer { id: "answerID" }) with a match a<-[:CHOSE]-(u: User) return count(u)`?  If you dump your data what does it look like?

Comment: I'm using community-2.2.1 FWIW.  Also, you might try it on http://console.neo4j.org/ and if it's not working there use the "Share" button

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible that you have to different Answer nodes with id="answerId" ? Check using:

```
MATCH (a:Answer{id:'answerID'}) return count(a)
```

If this gives a result > 1 it would prove my theory. In this case one of them would be connected to a `Question` and another one might be connected to a `User`.

Duplicated nodes can occur if e.g. you use non-granular `MERGE`s in `LOAD CSV`.

Comment: yes, there were different nodes with id="answerId".
You were right Stefan

Comment: you could use [unique constraints](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/query-constraints.html#constraints-create-uniqueness-constraint) on `answerId` to make sure there are no duplicates